# Alignment out of place when done through cgi-perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I've been trying to implement global alignment algorithm using cgi bioperl. The code works fine and the alignment between the two sequences is perfect using a command prompt. But using cgi the alignment of the two sequences is not perfect. It kinda moves out of place. Here's my code for alignment:

```
@firstarray = split //, $align1;
@secondarray = split //, $align2;

$sizeoffirst = $#firstarray + 1;
$sizeofsecond = $#secondarray + 1;

print "$sizeoffirst\n"."<br/>";
print "$sizeofsecond\n"."<br/>";

$k = 0;
while ($k <= $sizeoffirst)
  {
    $count = 1;
    $l = $k;
    while ($count <= 30)
      {
        print $firstarray[$l];
        $count++;
        $l++
      }
    print "\n"."<br/>";

    $count = 1;
    $m = $k;
    while ($count <= 30)
      {
        print $secondarray[$m];
        $count++;
        $m++;
      }

    print "\n"."<br/>";
    print "\n"."<br/>";
    $count = 1;
    $k = $k + 30;
  }
```

The "dash"(in order to denote a gap) is quite smaller as compare to the letters. Hence the alignment moves out of the place. What can I do?

Comment: you should use `<pre>` so that your formatting is maintained on a web page.

Comment: Or a `<table>`. It's the way to display tabulated data. Also, ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `<pre>` so that your formatting is maintained on a web page.
                    – Barmar

Or a `<table>`. It's the way to display tabulated data. Also, ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;`.
                    – Toto